# What are alternatives of "a better way" in academic writing?

Tags: academia

I want to say "`A better way to analyse the .. is to understand its underlying structure`". What are the alternatives to saying `a better way`?

Comment: Change "analyse" to analysis: "An improved analysis of ... comes from understanding of its underlying structure". Or maybe "An improved method to analyse..." Then check a [thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/better?s=t) for synonyms of improved/better (and "way").

Comment: Or perhaps, "*Greater understanding of ... will come from thorough/detailed/further/deeper analysis of its underlying structure.*"

Answer (score 1):

It is common to use the word "elegant" for such a descriptor in academia.

> "An **elegant** way to analyse the (or "An **elegant** analysis of") .. is to
>   understand its underlying structure".

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/elegant

https://www.freethesaurus.com/elegant